# Using malloc on a elemnt in struct in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[3];
    int month_num;
    int day_num;
    int day_size; // amount of days that are field in with tasks.
    char *task[40];
}

month; // each month contains a name, its num in the calendar and days.
```

and I need to assign memory allocation for it.
I was able to assign the memory for the struct itself:

```
mon = (month*)malloc(12 * sizeof(month));
```

But I am having trouble to do it the same for the char *task[40].

I tried a lot of possibilities, but non of them worked...

```
char temptask[40];
mon->task=malloc(strlen(temptask)+1);
```

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: You should `malloc()` for `mon->task[0]` and/or other elements not `mon->task`.

Comment: First: What type is `task`, in English?

Comment: well, since task is in the struct named month, then i'll say it's in the type month. (if in type you mean as if in int, char, double, etc.)

Comment: @lili No, not "what type is it inside?" but "what type is it?"

Comment: i don't really understand waht you mean...

Comment: `int i;` <- now `i` is an integer. `month m;` <- now `m.task` is what? (I'm testing your understanding; this is not part of an answer)

Comment: mon.task is a string, an array of chars

Comment: Nope, it's not. (How would you define an array of chars?)

Comment: well i do think it is a string (but since task has a pointer then it is an array of pointers)

Comment: @lil A value in C can't be "a string" and "an array of pointers" at the same time, they are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<40;i++)
{ 
  /* Allocating memory to each pointers and later you write to this location */
  mon->task[i] = malloc(size);/* If you have a initialized string then size = strlen(tempTask) + 1 */
}
```

What you have is array of pointers and just access them and allocate memory to each of the pointers individually as shown above.

Comment: i have tried that option but for some reason the compailer screms: "="- cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'

Comment: What compiler are you using that can't convert from `void*` to `char*`?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @JohnZwinck Sounds like a C++ compiler to me. :(

Comment: @unwind You should be right. The most acclaimed answer of yours not to cast `malloc()`  answers the OP's question :)

Comment: @lili: If you're using a C++ compiler you need to cast the result of malloc, like `(char*)malloc(...)`.

Comment: Better: If you use a C++ compiler, you should program in C++. Use `new`, `delete` etc. If you want to program in C, use a C compiler (resp. tell your compiler to compile in C).

Answer (score 0):

`char *task[40];` is an array of 40 pointers.  You probably want a single array of 40 characters, in which case no need to malloc it separately, or else a single pointer in which case you can `malloc(40)`.  You can't call `strlen()` on an uninitialized C string, that's undefined behavior (buffer overrun).

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you need is

```
char *task;
```

and then allocate memory as

```
mon[j].task=malloc(sizeof(temptask));
```

Next, as you've allocated memory to `mon` as

```
 mon = malloc(12 * sizeof(month));
```

the access should be made as

```
 mon[j].task  // j being the index, running from 0 to 11
```

Otherwise, if you really have a `char *task[40];`, that means, an array of `40` `char *`s, then you have to allocate memory for *each of them*, one by one.

```
int p = strlen(temptask);
for(i=0;i<40;i++)
{
      mon[j].task[i] = malloc(p+1);
}
```

Comment: What you're proposing is undefined behavior!

Comment: @JohnZwinck I really appreciate leaving the comment along with the downvote. Can you please elaborate a bit, as i'm not clear on the reason behind undefined behaviour here.

Comment: It's undefined behavior to call `strlen(temptask)` when `temptask` is an uninitialized C string.  This UB was in the OP as well.  There's no need for the `temptask` variable at all.

Comment: why do i need to write     mon[i]    if month are going to max 12? why is going from 0 to 39?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Is it better now?

Comment: @lili `mon[0]` will be the first month, `mon[1]` will be the second and so on. each month will be represented by a structure variable in the array

Comment: @lili aah, I din't mean to have to loop for 40 times. for clarification, let's use `j` as index to `mon`. Clear?